# How to add a fee to a fee in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I know it may seem a bit contrived but I'm looking to add a fee to a fee in WooCommerce. We use a tip plugin that accounts for tips as a "fee". We also surcharge at 3.99% as a "convenience fee".

The problem is that our convenience fee does not calculate properly if someone adds a tip. We calculate for cart total, tax, and shipping total but not the fees. We're not getting any value returned from the variable `$tip` at the moment. When hard coding in what `$fee` value is, it calculates perfectly, which leads me to believe we're just not sorting through the object correctly.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );

function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
    global $woocommerce;

    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_fees() as $fee_id => $fee) {
        if ($fee['name'] == 'Tip (10%)') {
            $tip = $fee['amount'];
        }
    }

    $percentage = 0.0399;
    
    $surcharge = (
        $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total +
        $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total + 
        $woocommerce->cart->get_tax_totals +
        $tip
    ) * $percentage;
    
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Convenience Fee', $surcharge, false, '' );
}
```

Comment: Start by making a debug output of what `$woocommerce->cart->get_fees()` actually returns.

Comment: We're tried and got really nothing to actually show up there. Debug mode was on and everything. We did get something to print to the Javascript console using a little PHP to Javascript trickery, and we did not see in that object the variable, or rather key, we were searching for. However, when switching out the names of what we have with what we did see, we still saw no output. Leads me to believe we're sorting through the object incorrectly...

Comment: Could you add to this post: (a) a numbers example of a correct run with the code as it is, without a tip; (b) an example of an incorrect run with the code as it is, with a tip; (c) an example of what the numbers with a tip should look like. I think you have a maths problem here, but have not made it clear to readers how the calculations should be applied. Thanks!

Comment: I could do that, but the math is actually pretty solid, or it seems so anyways. When we hard code in tip, it works as expected. The issue is actually finding the tips value based on that specific cart state. I believe we're looping through the object incorrectly.